# print the count of files for each sub folder iterativly

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, data-cleaning

I have the following folder structure:

```
A/B/C/D/E/00
A/B/C/D/E/01
.
.
A/B/C/D/E/23
```

Similarly,

```
M/N/O/P/Q/00
M/N/O/P/Q/01
.
.
M/N/O/P/Q/23
```

Now, each folder from 00 to 23 has many files inside, which I would like to count.

If I run this simple command:

ls /A/B/C/D/E/00 | wc -l
I can get the count of files in each of these sub directories. I want to automate this or get it iteratively. 
Also, the final output I am looking at is a file that should look like this:

```
C E RESULT OF ls /A/B/C/D/E/00 | wc -l RESULT OF ls /A/B/C/D/E/01 | wc -l
M Q RESULT OF ls /M/N/O/P/Q/00 | wc -l RESULT OF ls /M/N/O/P/Q/01 | wc -l
```

So, the output should look like this finally

```
C E 23 23 4 6  7  4 76 98 57 2 67 9 12 34 67 0 2 3  78 98 12 3  57 213
M Q 12 10 2 34 32 1 35 65 87 8 32 2 65 87 98 0 4 12 1  35 34 76 9  67
```

Please note, the values after the alphabets are the values of file counts of the 24 folders 00, 01 through 23.

Using the eval approach: I can hardcode and get the exact results. But, I wanted it in a way that would show me the data for the previous day. So this is what I did:

```
d=`date --date ="1 days ago" +%Y%m%d`
month= `date +%Y%m`
eval echo YZ $d '"$(ls "/A/B/YZ/$month/$d/"'{20150800..20150823})'| wc -l)"'
```

This works perfectly because in the given location there are files inside child directories 20150800,20150801..20150823. However when I try to generalize this like below, it shows no such file or directory:

```
eval echo YZ $d '"$(ls "/A/B/YZ/$month/$d/"'{"$d"00.."$d"23})'| wc -l)"'
```

Is there something I am missing in the above line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very safe way of counting files:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -exec printf x \; | wc -c
```

To not count recursively add `-maxdepth 1` before `-exec`.

Some other notes:

- `eval` is evil. Don't use it. There is only one place I've ever seen where it's appropriate, and that's when using `getopt`.
- [You should not parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).
- [Use `$()` for command substitutions](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution).